# Gaussian Negative log likelihood loss vs MSE

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions, mse

I'm training a neural network on a regression problem. I wanted to compare between (1) Gaussian negative log likelihood (GNLL) loss (the output of the network is the mean and log variance) and (2) the MSE loss (the output of the network is the mean only). I noticed that when using MSE, the MSE loss gets close to zero. However, when I use GNLL loss, MSE decreases but stays large. Why is it difficult for the neural network to reduce MSE when using GNLL as a loss function?

Comment: Do you know the formula/equation being used in the software to calculate the Gaussian negative log-likelihood? The GNLL are MSE are equivalent as loss functions, but if one has a constant out front, that could change the story about the value achieved at their common $\arg\min$.

Comment: @Dave The formula is given here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GaussianNLLLoss.html